# Proxy's model function isn't called

Tags: c++, qt

I've connected source model to my proxy model and my proxy model as a model to a view:

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),model_(new Model(this)),proxy_(new Proxy(this))
{
    setupUi(this);
    proxy_->setSourceModel(model_);

    listView->setModel(proxy_);

}
```

In Proxy class I have a fnc:

```
int Proxy::rowCount(const QModelIndex&) const
{
    static int a = 0;
    qDebug() << "Proxy::rowCount sourceModel()->rowCount() " << a++ << ": "<< sourceModel()->rowCount();
    return sourceModel()->rowCount();
}
```

but this is not called when I add something to view via model's fnc:

```
bool Model::set_data(int data)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(),0,data_.size());
    data_.append(data);
    static int a = 0;
    qDebug() << "Model::set_data data_ " << a++ << ":" << data_;
    endInsertRows();
    emit dataChanged(createIndex(0,0),createIndex(data_.size(),0));
    return true;
}
```

The function above is connected via SIGNAL SLOT connection a button on a dialog:
 QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), Dialog, SLOT(insert())); and the insert from dialog looks like this:

```
 bool Dialog::insert()
 {
     static int a = 0;
     return model_->set_data(a++);

 }
```

But despite all this view doesn't show anything. On the other hand if I connect as a model to a view my Model class obj instead of Proxy everything works.
Anyone have any idea what's wrong here?
EDIT:: 
After testing model:

```
ASSERT failure in QList<T>::at: "index out of range", file c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 456
```

After testing just proxy:

```
D:\...\tst_mpv.exe exited with code -1073741819
```

My main fnc looks:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "Dialog.h"
#include "Model.h"
#include "Proxy.h"
#include "modeltest.h"
int main(int c,char**v)
{
    QApplication app(c,v);
    /*Model* m = new Model;
    new ModelTest(m);*/
    Proxy* p = new Proxy;
    new ModelTest(p);
    /*Dialog d;
    d.show();*/
    return app.exec();
}
```

here are my Model and Proxy classes: http://pastebin.com/DiAAkiNY

Comment: What proxy model are you using, is it `QSortFilterProxyModel` derived or your own `QAbstractProxyModel` derived proxy? Have you used the [Model Test](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Model_Test) to check for errors?

Comment: @skyhisi it is my own proxy model.

Comment: Have you used Model Test on it then?

Comment: @skyhisi I'm going to do it now. I'll let you know in few minutes what's the results;

Comment: I'm getting after setting in main Proxy* p = new Proxy; new TestModel(proxy); following error: myproxymodel data 
ASSERT: "QTest::testLogger" in file c:\ndk_buildrepos\qt-desktop\src\testlib\qtestlog.cpp, line 232

Comment: continue: interestingly the location specified c:\ndk... doesn't exist.

Comment: It may be better to edit your question with the results of using model test so they can be correctly formatted. Make sure you have attached a model tester to both your source and proxy model, incase the source model is faulty.

Comment: Now you have an error message to work with! Run the program under a debugger, get the stack-trace. It will probably pass through the model tester, read the comments in the model tester source code to see what was being tested and triggered the error.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do it right now and I'll let you know how it went. Thanks.

Comment: @skyhisi ok, I did the model test. I fixed index - it was creating incorrect indexes. I also added setHeader into Proxy class. Now it doesn't crash anymore. Sad news are that it still won't display data into view.

Comment: Have you put a model tester on the source model?

Comment: @skyhisi yes, I did and test doesn't show anything. Maybe you could look at the code I've provided in edit and see it for yourself. Do I need to connect any slots from view to any of those models?

Comment: Views connect themselves to the model. Try calling `QAbstractItemModel::beginResetModel` and `QAbstractItemModel::endResetModel` around any data changes instead of row change and data change. If that works then your signal emission is faulty, note that resetting the model can be slow as it triggers full reloads in the proxies and views.

Comment: @skyhisi did you try my source code? And no, beginResetModel doesn't make any change - still nothing. I think it would be better if you check my source code - otherwise is a guesswork.

Comment: @skyhisi the problem is that Proxy's fncs mapToSource and mapFromSource are not called. I've just checked with qDebug.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example of a proxy model, using (as recommended in the documentation) a `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Building up from the `QSortFilterProxyModel` is the easiest way as all the tricky bits are done.

**test.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "proxy.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        QStringList list;
        list << "ant" << "bear" << "cat" << "dog";

        QStringListModel mdl(list);

        QListView viewRaw;
        viewRaw.setModel(&mdl);
        viewRaw.show();

        Proxy proxy;
        proxy.setSourceModel(&mdl);

        QListView viewPrx;
        viewPrx.setModel(&proxy);
        viewPrx.show();

        return app.exec();
}
```

**proxy.h**

```
#ifndef _PROXY_H_
#define _PROXY_H_

#include <QtGui>

class Proxy : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
        public:
                virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
};

#endif
```

**proxy.cpp**

```
#include "proxy.h"

QVariant Proxy::data(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex, int role) const
{
        QVariant d = QSortFilterProxyModel::data(proxyIndex, role);
        if (proxyIndex.isValid() && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
                return QVariant(QString("[[%1]]").arg(d.toString()));
        return d;
}
```

**test.pro**

```
QT += core gui
SOURCES=test.cpp proxy.cpp
HEADERS=proxy.h
```

Comment: but I need to subclass QAbstractProxyModel. Would you mind showing me how to properly do it with QAbstractProxyModel?